# replace real data source with embedded database for tests

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, junit5

I have two data sources in my spring boot application. both declared like:

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.nws.signer.db.dao",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "signerEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "signerTransactionManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SignerJPAConfig {
    private Map<String, String> sig_db_props;
    private String sig_url;

    @Autowired
    private VedProfiledPropsSource p;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sig_db_props = new HashMap<>();

        sig_url =
                String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s", p.getSigDbHost(), p.getSigDbPort(), p.getSigDbName());

        sig_db_props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect");
        sig_db_props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", sig_url);
        sig_db_props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", p.getSigDbUser());
        sig_db_props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", p.getSigDbPassword());
        sig_db_props.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");
        sig_db_props.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        sig_db_props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    }
...
}
```

so I am using `VedProfiledPropsSource` which is `@ConfigurationProperties` with properties for specific profile used. after initializing jpaPropertyMap in postConstruct I am setting it to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` which is declared as a bean alongside with `DataSource` and `PlatformTransactionManager`. same for the other data source.

Now I want to use `embedded-database-spring-test` dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to bootstrap the embedded database for tests and connect my data sources to this database. the build machine doesn't have a database so I want to use this within the test scope.

my e2e test class starts with:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {VedicaConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("mvntest")
@FlywayTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(beanName = "signerJPAConfig")
public class RESTTest {
...
}
```

so I was thinking it will bootstrap the in-memory postgresql db and replace (by magic) the named data source anf flyway will apply migration scripts.

now I am missing/misunderstanding something as this is not happening and my data source configuration bean is still trying to connect to the database with credentials correctly red from profiled property file. and it fails with:

```
2019-10-07 00:05:53.785 ERROR 40358 --- [  prefetching-3] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error: 

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:245) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) [spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) [flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72) [flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670) [flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) [flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.flyway.DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext$FlywayDatabasePreparer.prepare(DefaultFlywayDataSourceContext.java:173) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance$DatabaseTemplate.<init>(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:147) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance$DatabaseTemplate.<init>(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:136) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance$1.load(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:120) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance$1.load(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:118) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3957) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4875) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4881) [signer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider$DatabaseInstance.getTemplate(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:133) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.getDatabase(ZonkyPostgresDatabaseProvider.java:94) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.lambda$new$0(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:252) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at io.zonky.test.db.provider.impl.PrefetchingDatabaseProvider$PrefetchingTask.run(PrefetchingDatabaseProvider.java:259) [embedded-database-spring-test-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

please advice me what should I do in order to replace my real data source with embedded one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked. If you have a Spring boot project with JPA (Entities and Repositories), you can create the following test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = { LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
public class JpaTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void create(){
    ...
    }
```

Be sure to set the following properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
```